# How to handle - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url in storyboard application?

Tags: ios

I want to open certain images with my application. I have set up URL schemes and everything is fine, I get to this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)source annotation:(id)annotation
```

But how do I access my view controller after this and tell it to open the image in my image view?

I don't have pointer to Storyboard, or to my view controller, and how do I prevent further loading of application in regular manner?

For example I open certain image on startup and I don't want to do that if I was told to open another file from another application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use self.window form the app delegate to access the root view controller. Then navigate from there, such as subviews and instances of the classes.

A more detailed answer:
Let say the root view controller is a MasterViewController, which is a subclass of UIViewController.
In that MasterViewController you have a UIView, and in that is a UIImageView.

Use UIWindow to get the root view controller, from the AppDelegate:

```
MasterViewController *master = (MasterViewController *)[self.window rootViewController]);
```

Since you're smart you setup your storyboard so the UIImageView has a property in the MasterViewController, let's call it imageView.
So it's so easy, just do:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [master imageView];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[url path]]];
```

Something like that.
You will need to import all classes you use, such as MasterViewController.